# Bootstrap Carousel Caption Disappears When Larger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am using bootstrap to create a web page, I am trying to get the carousel to slide thru some images and I have copied the majority of it from the template. My problem is the captions seem to disappear when the width of the browser is larger.

I copied the code and css from this example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/wood.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Web Design</h1>
          <p class="lead">A snappy website will attract new people!</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/wood.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>App Design</h1>
          <p class="lead">CA App will let you reach out to your followers!</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/wood.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Database Design</h1>
          <p class="lead">Databases are key to a companies success now adays!</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: There doesn't look to be anything wrong with your HTMl so the problem probably lies elsewhere. Can you provide a link to your web page or recreate the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: @BillyMoat mcalcse.appspot.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to include the Bootstrap responsive css file too.

It should be added after the regular bootstrap.css file e.g.

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```